# trying to connect to remote Exchange server 2007 from powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2007

Am getting SSL error while connecting to remote exchange server.

Can any one help me.

Comment: Try to use more meaningful tags than "Microsoft" .....

Comment: how are you connecting? what cmdlets? example code will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a completely random guess at this near-empty question, I'd say your exchange server is using a privately issued SSL certificate and the workstation that you are trying to connect to it  from doesn't have the Root CA (it doesn't trust the remote SSL cert)

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting with something like WFetch. This will help you get a meaningful response from Exchange when attempting to connect. Also i agree with **x0n** , it sounds like you are missing certificate which is required when connecting over SSL.